# Empty parameter for LIKE in Oracle sql should be false

Tags: oracle

I am running a query on Oracle, Where I need to select data on three parameters.
ID, MNO, NAME
here is my query look like

```
SELECT *
  FROM USER_TABLE
 WHERE L_ID <> 1111
       AND (   ID = ''
            OR MNO = '0215421101'
            OR FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME LIKE '%' || '' || '%') //when Empty, search only return values for MNO
```

This is returning all results because empty space matches in all records. How should I limit this to only MNO or ID when FIRST_NAME + LAST_NAME is Empty string

Update::

this when data is returned from name parameter.

```
SELECT *
  FROM USER_TABLE
 WHERE L_ID <> 1111
       AND (   ID = ''
            OR MNO = ''
            OR FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME LIKE '%' || 'User Name' || '%') //when have value, search only return values for NAme
```

Comment: `FIRST_NAME is Null and LAST_NAME is Null`? Empty string is `null` in case of Oracle

Comment: I don't understand. If you look for a name (e.g. parameter name = 'User Name') your query only returns matches for the name. If you don't look for a name (i.e. the parameter name is ''), then your results are not limited by name. Sounds perfect to me. What do you want different? Please show results you are getting for a set of parameters and the result rows you are expecting instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add [nvl](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) for each parameter, and it'll check against current value (always true)

```
 Or FIRST_NAME = nvl(?,FIRST_NAME) and LAST_NAME = nvl(?,LAST_NAME)
```

> NVL lets you replace null (returned as a blank) with a string in the results of a query. If expr1 is null, then NVL returns expr2. If expr1 is not null, then NVL returns expr1.

Comment: my problem is that, I am providing name paramter for both FirstName and LastName to search, but when I don't want to send that parameter, query should not run that area

Comment: @trighati Add check `nvl` of parameter. see my update answer

Answer (score 0):

Use either nvl or Decode function for removing the space before string and after string use trim according to stored database value.